# Mediawiki extension that allows me to confirm user contributions before they are applied to the actual wiki

Tags: spam, mediawiki

I am running more of a informational wiki. I keep registrations open for users who want to edit the pages that are not in English, however I am having a problem with spam. I am looking for an extension that allows me to confirm/review user contributions before they are applied to the real page. I know there is the `Special:RecentChanges` but by the time I look at that special page, spam could already exist and backlinks to the spam can bring my website rank down. I am looking for something that prevents that step and allows me to make sure the edits people are trying to make are good/useful.

Features I am looking for

- Allows user to edit or create a new page, but the changes won't be applied until I say its ok
- There should be some type of review queue where I can view the awaiting change list
- Button to confirm or deny changes (and mass confirm/deny)
- Comparision of the new/old changes (side by side)

Comment: Why don't you use the Askimet extension to prevent from spam?

Comment: Making my former answer a comment since @aman207 responded to it but it was better suited as a comment: ave you tried either of the options listed in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813277/mediawiki-moderation? For example: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Approved_Revs and http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FlaggedRevs

Answer (score 1):

The [explainxkcd](http://explainxkcd.com) wiki uses [Extension:ConfirmEdit](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmEdit), which is bundled with MediaWiki so you don't have to install anything. It forces users who have neither the `autoconfirmed` nor the `confirmed` (the one admins give you) permissions to get rate throttled for certain actions (e.g. editing) and to solve captchas (the type of which you can select) before performing some of these actions. This also lets you implement something like Wikipedia's [edit request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Edit_requests) system, which is what you seem to be looking for.

Another one I found was [Extension:Antispam](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Antispam), which is a client-side service for [CleanTalk](https://cleantalk.org), an anti-spam service that also lets you confirm edits. However, it has a pricing model, which seems to me like a bit of a turn-off.

[Extension:Patroller](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Patroller) enhances the recent changes interface and thus allows you to do what you want, but it's incompatible with MW 1.23 (and thus unstable).

Also, as Skram noted, there are two extensions posted as answers to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4813277/1757964):

- [Extension:FlaggedRevs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3AFlaggedRevs), which allows users with the `reviewer` right to rate revisions in terms of accuracy, depth, and readability. All "current" versions (i.e. those resulting from edits made since the "stable" version) are treated as drafts. As the banner at the bottom of the page notes, it's used on one or more Wikimedia projects, so it's likely to work well.
- [Extension:ApprovedRevs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Approved_Revs), which claims on its MediaWiki description page to be a lightweight alternative to Extension:FlaggedRevs. It suggests that you use it for small- to medium-scale wikis. Anyone with the `approverevisions` permision can mark a specific version of a page as "approved", which turns that version into the one users are given when they visit the page's main URL.